# Set PHP path correctly for MAMP Pro

Tags: php, bash, shell, mamp

MAMP Pro makes you edit a php.ini template through the application and it creates the file in `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini` each time MAMP Pro is started. How do I get it to use this php.ini on the command line? I have this entry in my `.bash_profile` file currently:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH
```

This shows the correct PHP version at the command line, but the wrong config file:

```
$ php -i | grep php\.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf
Loaded Configuration File => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini
$ php --version
PHP 5.4.4 (cli) (built: Jul  4 2012 17:28:56)
```

How can I get this to work so that it uses the php.ini file from the path in the first paragraph? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose MAMP is setting the ini-Path dynamically upon start. To get the same behavior on the command line you can pass the ini-path to php via the `-c` argument.

```
php -c /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/conf/php.ini
```

For more comfort you could add this as an alias to your `.bash_profile`

```
alias php='php -c /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/conf/php.ini'
```